# blue dot for current location in react-google-maps

Tags: angularjs, node.js, reactjs, react-google-maps

I want to add blue dot for my current location in my project. Code for my map file is this way

state is

```
this.state={
  currentPosition:{lat: 26.84   ,lng: 75.80},
  destinationPosition:{lat: 26.84   ,lng: 75.80}
};
```

handleClick for current location is

```
handleClick(){
    if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position)=>{
            this.setState(()=>({
                currentPosition:{
                    lat:position.coords.latitude,
                    lng:position.coords.longitude}}))
            console.log(position.coords.latitude);
        }); 
    }
    else{
        alert("Geoloaction is not supported by your browser");
    }
}
```

and render function is in this way

```
render(){
  const MyMapComponent = compose(
    withProps({
      googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC5VMMlyr_A6K5ycpOrq3OsVM8YYbn0q3A&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
      loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
      containerElement: <div style={{ height: `300px` }} />,
      mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    }),
    withScriptjs,
    withGoogleMap
    )((props) =>
      <GoogleMap defaultZoom={15} defaultCenter= 
        {this.state.destinationPosition} >
        <Marker position={this.state.destinationPosition} draggable 
           changeLat
           onDragEnd={this.onMarkerPositionChanged.bind(this)}
        />

        <Button bsStyle="success" onClick= 
            {this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Current Position</Button>
        </GoogleMap>
    );

    return(
      <Container 
         text={<Text lat={this.state.destinationPosition.lat} 
         lng={this.state.destinationPosition.lng}/>} 
         map={<MyMapComponent />} 
      />

    );
}
```

Also please tell me how can i include both marker and blue dot in my map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
render() {
    const MyMapComponent = compose(
        withProps({
            googleMapURL:
                'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC5VMMlyr_A6K5ycpOrq3OsVM8YYbn0q3A&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places',
            loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
            containerElement: <div style={{ height: `300px` }} />,
            mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />
        }),
        withScriptjs,
        withGoogleMap
    )(props => (
        <GoogleMap defaultZoom={15} defaultCenter={this.state.destinationPosition}>
            <Marker
                position={this.state.destinationPosition}
                draggable
                changeLat
                onDragEnd={this.onMarkerPositionChanged.bind(this)}
            />

            //this is your current location blue dot
            //could replace it with the icon you like
            <Marker
                icon="https://www.robotwoods.com/dev/misc/bluecircle.png"
                position={this.state.currentPosition}
            />

            <Button bsStyle="success" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
                Current Position
            </Button>
        </GoogleMap>
    ));

    return (
        <Container
            text={
                <Text
                    lat={this.state.destinationPosition.lat}
                    lng={this.state.destinationPosition.lng}
                />
            }
            map={<MyMapComponent />}
        />
    );
}
```

Comment: can you also tell me how can i stop re-rendering on the map because when i change state map is loaded again. so is their any better way to store positions other than state.

Comment: You could store your positions in state, which is totally fine. Not sure what you mean by "map is loaded again". If you mean the postion of marker changed, that's good. If you mean the whole map got refreshed, it might have something to do with how you build your <Container />.  You probably should just render your "text" and "map" directly instead of passing them to <Container /> That is my guess because I dont have all your codes.

Comment: i understand what you are saying, you want me to import <Text/> and <MyMapComponent/> in <Container/>, but then how will i use the state which i am passing as props to the <Text/> and <MyMapComponent/>.

Comment: In your <MyMapComponent/>, read data from "props" instead of "this.state". You could pass "this.state" to <Container/> as a prop, then in <Container/> you pass this prop to <Text/> and <MyMapComponent/>